# wso2 carbon bind address

Tags: wso2

I would like to control which network address carbon bind the http/https connector to when starting up.

Is it possible to configure carbon to bind to a particular IP address?  I'm looking for the carbon alternative of the address attribute of a tomcat connector:

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Connectors#Q6

I have tried to configure the address in `$CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml`.  I set the `address=127.0.0.1`, but carbon management UI still bound to non-localhost adapter (192.168.0.10).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `<CARBON_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.xml` there are 2 commented elements as:

```
<!--HostName>www.wso2.org</HostName-->

<!--MgtHostName>mgt.wso2.org</MgtHostName-->
```

Uncomment these two and add correct host names/ip addresses.